# One ViewModel containing a collection of ViewModels, different Views depending on value of ViewModel property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am new to the MVVM-pattern, and am trying out Caliburn.Micro on a project.

I want to have one ViewModel (which contains a collection of ViewModels) shared by multiple Views, where each view only displays items which have a certain value on one of it's properties.

To get specific, I am using a service which allows me to monitor different values that update frequently. I then get an object of type MonitoredItem, which contains a property of type `DataValue`, which in turn contains an object for the Value and a property for the value's datatype.

So far I have a `MonitoredItemViewModel` which uses this service's `MonitoredItem` class as it's model, and a `MonitoredItemsViewModel` which contains `BindableCollection<MonitoredItemViewModel>` MonitoredItems, and commands for adding/removing items.

I also have a `MonitoredItemsView` where I can see all the items I am currently monitoring.

How do I go about splitting up the view, so that I can have all `MonitoredItems` where `DataValue` is an integer/float/double displayed in one area in my window, boolean values displayed somewhere else etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it in the view, instead expose different collections on your ViewModels according to what you need to filter.

This can be done either as known collections, e.g.

```
public ObservableCollection<MonitoredItemViewModel> ItemsWhereFooIsBar ...
public ObservableCollection<MonitoredItemViewModel> ItemsWhereFooIsntBar ...
```

or you could do it more generically to return filtered collections on demand

```
public ObservableCollection<MonitoredItemViewModel> GetItems(Func<DataValue, bool> matches)
{
   //Filter collection with 
   return ... allItems.Where(x=>matches(x))... ;
}
```

and call via

```
GetItems(x=>x.Foo == Bar)
```

The problem you are going to have is when the items change and should switch from collection to collection. If you were using [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/) this would be incredibly easy as you can use Rx to trigger its built in item tracking and also use its `.CreateDerivedCollection(...)` to build the new collections automatically (hint, hint :-))

If not then you have a few choices.

- You can derive a class from ObservableCollection so that as well as being notified via `CollectionChanged` when new items are added or removed, or also get notified when the properties of the items change as well.
- Or you could make your `ItemViewModel` immutable so that its properties never change, but instead you drop the old item and add an updated one into the correct collection.

Comment: I listed some alternatives to ReactiveUI on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780608#15035000).

Comment: Thanks for this suggested way of solving my problem. I shall try this out

Comment: @HappyNomad Thanks, I'll have a look at those. Nice to know you don't have to reinvent the wheel every time